new to assembler(nasm) cant find out whats going on (or wrong)
i spent some hours to get into assembler and went for a decimal to binary conversion program. i spent hours :/ but dont get why im not getting any output here :
section .data
    decimal:     db  "enter decimal"
    decimalLen:  equ $-decimal
    binaer: db 'Binary equivalent',10
    binaerLen: equ  $-binaer
    nummer  dq 546
    zaehler  dq 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    and rsp, -16
    mov rax,[nummer]
    mov r8,[zaehler]

LOOP:
    cmp rax,0
    je LOOP2
    inc r8
    xor rdx,rdx
    mov rcx,2
    div rcx
    mov rcx,rax
    push rdx
    jmp LOOP

LOOP2:
    cmp r8,0
    je END
    dec r8
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    pop rsi
    add rsi,'0'
    mov rdx,1
    syscall
    jmp LOOP2

END:
    mov rax,1
    int 80h


first of all i tried to find a program or online compiler that gives me some hints about whats wrong, but every site / program fired different errors / results. consulted chat gpt all the time, but its no help either. i guess im missing basic concepts, but got no clue.
i btw removed all comments because they were in german and were mostly a reminder of how instructions work in general.

you are not giving us a lot of info about the errors, but for sys_write syscall, rsi register holds a pointer to the buffer, not the actual to print.

This approach, of pushing digits into the stack and then popping them one by one and printing them, is bizarre.  Please store the digits into a buffer, and then print the buffer.

@MikeNakis I have seen the single digit through stack approach often. It isn't unusual for a beginner. It likely performs worse but as a lesson in how to use the stack and loops it's fine I think.

The first loop starts by skipping if RAX is zero. Don't you want the number 0 to get printed? It also contains a redundant instruction mov rcx, rax that serves no purpose.
Good news
Dividing by 2 does not require an actual division. You can use a simple shift to the right, followed by processing the carry that it produces.
I prefer to use a sentinel on the stack instead of maintaining a count.
  xor  ecx, ecx  ; -> RCX=0
  push rcx       ; Push sentinel
LOOP1:
  shr  rax, 1
  setc cl        ; -> CL={0,1}
  add  cl, '0'   ; -> CL={'0','1'}
  push rcx       ; Push digit
  test rax, rax
  jnz  LOOP1


Because the first loop always pushes at least 1 digit, the second loop can have its iterating condition at the bottom (which is most efficient).
Bad news
As PawelLukasik mentioned, RSI must hold a pointer to the character that you want to display. That pointer is equal to the current stackpointer RSP:
LOOP2:
  mov  edx, 1    ; -> RDX=1
  mov  rsi, rsp
  mov  edi, edx  ; -> RDI=1
  mov  eax, edx  ; -> RAX=1
  syscall
  pop  rax       ; Remove digit from the stack
  cmp  byte [rsp], 0
  jne  LOOP2
  pop  rax       ; Remove the sentinel

